Making a video of dynamic output
I wrote a code which solves sudokus.
It's a while-loop that starts with the first field and systematically tests for each number if it is possible.
By using the Pause[] in the loop and  a Dynamic output I can monitor how the code is working.
Now I would like to make a video of the Dynamic output of the code.
I already made small videos of moving objects with Mathematica using Animate (moving them on a vector) or ListAnimate (making a video of a "flicker book").
However, in this case I don't have a value moving in a direction nor single pictures. Is there an option to also make a video of the dynamic output?
This is the code:
First for the Output
Dynamic[Row[Framed /@ {grids[grid],Grid[{{"a", "x", "y", "c1", "Loop Count"}, {a, x, y, c1,LoopCount}}]}]]
Second to run the code:
(* Evaluate only once at the start! Describes the condition that the \
number isn't part of the 3x3 sub square*)
field = Which[
   (y == 1 || y == 2 || y == 3) && (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3), 
   grid[[1 ;; 3, 
    1 ;; 3]], (y == 1 || y == 2 || y == 3) && (x == 4 || x == 5 || 
      x == 6), 
   grid[[1 ;; 3, 
    4 ;; 6]], (y == 1 || y == 2 || y == 3) && (x == 7 || x == 8 || 
      x == 9), grid[[1 ;; 3, 7 ;; 9]],
   (y == 4 || y == 5 || y == 6) && (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3), 
   grid[[4 ;; 6, 
    1 ;; 3]], (y == 4 || y == 5 || y == 6) && (x == 4 || x == 5 || 
      x == 6), 
   grid[[4 ;; 6, 
    4 ;; 6]], (y == 4 || y == 5 || y == 6) && (x == 7 || x == 8 || 
      x == 9), grid[[4 ;; 6, 7 ;; 9]],
   (y == 7 || y == 8 || y == 9) && (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3), 
   grid[[7 ;; 9, 
    1 ;; 3]], (y == 7 || y == 8 || y == 9) && (x == 4 || x == 5 || 
      x == 6), 
   grid[[7 ;; 9, 
    4 ;; 6]], (y == 7 || y == 8 || y == 9) && (x == 7 || x == 8 || 
      x == 9), grid[[7 ;; 9, 7 ;; 9]]];

(*How to show the Grid*)
grids[grid_] := 
 Grid[grid, 
  Dividers -> {{False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, 
     False}, {False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, 
     False}}]
(*Solving mechanism:
a is the value that is tested, x and y determine the position in the \
grid (x column, y row), c1 is a control to avoid endless loops*)
solve := {a = x = y = 1; c1 = LoopCount = 0; 
  size = Length[gridstart[[1]]];
  grid = gridstart;
  While[MemberQ[grid, 0, All](*Checks if solved *), {
    If[a == 10, a = 1],
    If[c1 != 10,(*Control option to avoid EndlessLoop , 
     If c1 \[Equal] 10, activates correction function*)
     Which[
      (*If field is 0, a is legal option, 
      not last field in a row --\[Rule] insert a, 
      going a slot further in the row (x+1), control is 1, a is 1*)  
      grid [[y, x]] == 0 && 
       MemberQ[grid[[y]] || grid[[All, x]] || field, a, All] == 
        False && x < size, {grid[[y, x]] = a, x = x + 1, c1 = 1, 
       a = 1},
      (*If field is 0, a is legal option, 
      last field in a row --\[Rule] insert a,  
      beginning of new row(x is 1 & y is + 1), control is 1, a is 1*)  
      grid [[y, x]] == 0 && 
       MemberQ[grid[[y]] || grid[[All, x]] || field, a, All] == 
        False && x == size, {grid[[y, x]] = a, y = y + 1, x = 1, 
       c1 = 1, a = 1},
      (*If field is 0, a not a legal option --\[Rule] a + 
      1 and control + 1  as well *)
      grid [[y, x]] == 0 && 
       MemberQ[grid[[y]] || grid[[All, x]] || field, a, All], {a = 
        a + 1, c1 = c1 + 1},
      (*If field is start field, not last field of the row --\[Rule] 
      one slot in row further (x+1)*)
      grid [[y, x]] == gridstart[[y, x]] && x < size, {x = x + 1},
      (*If field is start field, n last field in a row --\[Rule] 
      beginning of new row(x is 1 & y is + 1)*)  
      grid [[y, x]] == gridstart[[y, x]] && x == size, {y = y + 1, 
       x = 1}
      ], {
      (*Control = EndlessLoop is triggered *)
      Which[
       (*Actual field is 0 and x not beginning of row, 
       one slot back (x-1)*)
       x != 1, {grid[[y, x]] = 0, x = x - 1, Lösung},
       (*Actual field is 0 and x beginning of row, 
       one row back and end of row (y-1 and x = 9)*)
       x == 1, {grid[[y, x]] = 0, y = y - 1, x = size, Lösung}]}],
    
    Pause[z],
    LoopCount = LoopCount + 1;
    }]}

(*correction mechanism*)
Lösung := {
  (* goes back until a field which isn't start field *)
  While[grid [[y, x]] == gridstart[[y, x]],
   {If[x != 1, x = x - 1, {y = y - 1, x = size}],
    Pause[z],
    LoopCount = LoopCount + 1}
   ],
  a = grid[[y, x]], (*a is value of the field which shall be correct*)

  
  While[c1 == 10, (*as long c1 is 10, correction mode doesn't end*)
   {Which[
     (*as long as a isn't legal option increase by 1*)
     grid [[y, x]] != gridstart[[y, x]] && 
      MemberQ[grid[[y]] || grid[[All, x]] || field, a, All], {a = 
       a + 1},
     (*if a is legal option and not end of the row --> insert a, 
     one slot further (x+1), control is 1, a is 1*)
     grid [[y, x]] != gridstart[[y, x]] && 
      MemberQ[grid[[y]] || grid[[All, x]] || field, a, All] == False &&
       x < size, {grid[[y, x]] = a, x = x + 1, a = 1, c1 = 1},
     (*If a is legal option, last field in a row --\[Rule] insert a, 
     one row further and beginning of row (x is 1 & y is + 1), 
     control is 1, a is 1*)  
     grid [[y, x]] != gridstart[[y, x]] && 
      MemberQ[grid[[y]] || grid[[All, x]] || field, a, All] == False &&
       x == size, {grid[[y, x]] = a, y = y + 1, x = 1, a = 1, c1 = 1}],
    Pause[z],
    LoopCount = LoopCount + 1,
    (*If no legal option for field (a\[Equal]10), 
    repeat control mechanism for field before*)
    If[a == 10, Which[ 
      x != 1, {grid[[y, x]] = 0, x = x - 1, Lösung},
      
      x == 1, {grid[[y, x]] = 0, y = y - 1, x = size, Lösung}]
     ]}]}

(*Length of pause*)
z = 0.001;
gridstart = {
   {0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 6, 9, 4, 3, 2, 0, 0},
   {0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0},
   {4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6},
   {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0},
   {6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8},
   {0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0},
   {0, 0, 1, 5, 7, 9, 3, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0}
   };
(*start mechanism*)
solve


Prepare an empty list, then append your rasterized version of output in each iteration of the loop ...? Difficult to give any other meaningful advice without your actual code (or at least a rough sketch of main parts).

I added the code I wrote. But the idea with the list is nice

Initialize an empty list of frames:
frames = {};

Then add a new frame after each iteration:
solve := (..., AppendTo[frames, grids[grid]]; Pause[z], ...);

Finally, export to the format of your liking:
Export["sudoku.mov", frames]

